Web API window.showDirectoryPicker is not working in Outlook 2024 and Office on the Web
I’ve been exploring a specific use-case related to checking out files to a specific folder. Normally, web browsers allow file downloads, but when we want to check out a file to a specific folder, we require user consent. One of the Web APIs that supports this feature is window.showDirectoryPicker.
Interestingly, it works seamlessly with Outlook 2023-08. However, I encountered an issue with Outlook 2024-05 and Outlook on the Web. The error message I received was:

DOMException: Failed to execute ‘showDirectoryPicker’ on ‘Window’: Cross-origin subframes aren’t allowed to show a file picker.

Here are the exact versions of Outlook where I observed this behavior:
Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2308 Build 16.0.16731.20542) 64-bit
Microsoft Outlook Version 1.2024.508.600 (Production). Client Version is 20240503010.51.
The window.showDirectoryPicker solution works flawlessly in Outlook 2023-08 and across all Office applications, including Word, Excel, and PowerPoint (version 2023-08). However, unfortunately, it doesn’t function in the latest versions of Outlook and other Office applications.
